# Leading to same value on Decryption with DESede CBC NoPadding

Tags: java, encryption, des

I am asked to verify if the encryption is working ok. I am given input hex text of 238 bytes. Asked to use DESede/CBC/NoPadding algorithm. I am also given encrypted value. Of course, I am given key also ( Given two bytes. Added third byte as copy of first byte to make it three bytes)

(238 bytes+ 2 bytes padding)

Problem is: Encrypted value from my code does not match completely with the given encrypted value ( only First 56 bytes are matching).

What I did is: Decrypted the given encrypted value and encrypted value produced from my code. Both of these decrypted values are matching with the given input.

That means, I have two encrypted values for which the decrypted value is the same.

Using InitialVector of Zeros.(8 zero bytes).

Can somebody throw some light? I am sure I am missing something. Thanks for any help.

Using javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance for getting Cipher instance. Using SecretKeyFactory and DESedeKeySpec classes to generate key

Edited:

```
public String encrypt(byte[] sourceDataInBytes, String keyInHex, String cryptoMode, String cryptoPadding)
    {
Cipher des3cipher = null;
IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = null;
String transformation = "DESede"+"/"+ cryptoMode+"/"+cryptoPadding;
byte[] encryptedDataInBytes = null;
try{
    des3cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
        Key key = generate3DESKey(keyInHex);
    if(cryptoMode.equalsIgnoreCase("CBC"))  
        {
            ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INITIAL_VECTOR_SALT);
            des3cipher.init(CYPHER_ENCRYPT_MODE, key, (AlgorithmParameterSpec)ivParamSpec );
        }else{
        des3cipher.init(CYPHER_ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        }

        if(cryptoPadding.equals("NoPadding")){'
    sourceDataInBytes = addPadding(sourceDataInBytes, 8);
    }
        encryptedDataInBytes = des3cipher.doFinal(sourceDataInBytes);
    }catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
    }
return encryptedDataInBytes ;
}

public Key generate3DESKey(String srcInHex)
{
Key key = null;
if(src != null)
{
    byte[] bk = null;
    try{
        bk = hexStringToByte(src + src.length==32 ? src.substring(0,16) : ""));

        DESedeKeySpec des3KeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(bk);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        key =  keyFactory.generateSecret(des3KeySpec);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e,printStyackTrace();
    }

}
return key;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible, so you should show us your code - there has to be a bug in it. If possible also show input / output test vectors.

Comment: Note that if you use CBC mode correctly (i.e. with a different IV every time the encryption method is called), you are _supposed_ to get a completely different ciphertext even for the same plaintext.

Comment: byte[] INITIAL_VECTOR_SALT = new byte[]{"0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00", "0x00"}

Comment: I am using  same initial vector.

Comment: The idea is that you send us an SSCCE, not some garbage that does not compile.